# cloning a github repo using ssh gives permission denied

Tags: ssh, github, ubuntu-20.04

I already generated a public key using `ssh-keygen`

running: `ssh -t git@github.com -v` gives:

```
OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.1, OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to github.com [13.234.176.102] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/nour/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: identity file /home/nour/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/nour/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/nour/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/nour/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/nour/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/nour/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /home/nour/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/nour/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /home/nour/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/nour/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /home/nour/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/nour/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /home/nour/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version babeld-bb759a61
debug1: no match: babeld-bb759a61
debug1: Authenticating to github.com:22 as 'git'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: rsa-sha2-512
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ssh-rsa SHA256:nThbg6kXUpJWGl7E1IGOCspRomTxdCARLviKw6E5SY8
debug1: Host 'github.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/nour/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/nour/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:1eKNsHmCFOimEVnvUX4YW0m1MZfPApUtGMDm400Nkdc
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/nour/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/nour/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/nour/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/nour/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/nour/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/nour/.ssh/id_xmss
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa,ssh-dss>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /home/nour/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:1eKNsHmCFOimEVnvUX4YW0m1MZfPApUtGMDm400Nkdc
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/nour/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/nour/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/nour/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk
debug1: Trying private key: /home/nour/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Trying private key: /home/nour/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk
debug1: Trying private key: /home/nour/.ssh/id_xmss
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
```

Comment: Did you upload that key [to GitHub](https://github.com/settings/keys)?

Comment: It is a public repo, why do I need to upload that?

Comment: Because you're connecting via SSH. GitHub doesn't support anonymous login via SSH.

Comment: @user1686 I see, thanks.